# Getting a single, random, related entry within a plug in

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, elementcriteriamodel

Given a Matrix with each row containing a text field and a multi relationship field. And I am picking 1 Matrix row based on the value in the text field. How would I go about selecting a single, random, related entry for that row?

I've tried to do this a couple of ways but I'm not really getting anywhere.

I'm selecting the Matrix row and getting the related entries using

```
$matrixRow = $entry->matrixField->textField($stringToMatch)->first();

$relatedEntries = $matrixRow->relationshipField;
```

But how can I now pick one of those related entries at random?
Is the only way to create an array and shuffle it?
Or is there a way I can do it when fetching the Matrix row?

I've tried adding the following in an attempt to get all the related entries associated with the Matrix row. Figuring I can then modify this query by adding a limit and ordering randomly to get my 1 related entry. But it's coming back empty.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section         = 'videos';
$criteria->relatedTo       = array(
    'targetElement'   => $matrixRow,
    'field'     => 'relationshipField'
);

$entries = $criteria->find();

foreach($entries as $entry){
    var_dump($entry->title);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$matrixRow->relationshipField` returns an ElementCriteriaModel pre-configured to query for the related elements. You can add / override additional criteria and then query for a matching element using the `first()` method.

```
$randomEntry = $matrixRow->relationshipField->order('RAND()')->first();
```

This is basically the same as what you’ve tried with your custom ElementCriteriaModel. It should also work once you have fixed the mistake in the `relatedTo` param, as the entry that holds the field is the “sourceElement” of a relation.

Comment: I have just discovered this and came here to edit my question. Brilliant! Makes life much easier!

Answer (score 1):

The `ElementCriteriaModel` has a function `nth($offset)` [link](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ElementCriteriaModel#nth-detail) so you could get a random number between 0 and `count()` and put it in your `nth()` function

```
$randomNumber = rand(0, $matrixRow->relationshipField->count());
$relatedEntry = $matrixRow->relationshipField->nth($randomNumber);
```

As an answer to your edit: you know that `$matrixRow->relationshipField` is nearly the same as your edit? `$matrixRow->relationshipField` is an object, it is not an array of elements. It has an iterable interface so the `$criteria->find()` method is executed as soon as you loop through it. So in the end the criteria you build is nearly the same object like Craft gives you with `$matrixRow->relationshipField`